# Is there a flexible way to modify the contents of an editable element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, text, google-chrome-extension

### Subject:

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that interacts with web pages via a content script and an event page.

I have context menu options that appear if a user clicks on an element that is categorized as `editable` by the [`chrome.contextMenus` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus).

The options act like shortcuts for commonly entered text. When the user clicks an option, some text is placed inside the element at the position of the cursor. If the user has text highlighted, it is deleted.

---

### Problem:

Not all editable elements can be modified the same way.

If the element is a simple `textarea` the desired result can be achieved by implementing this solution:

- [Replacing selected text in the textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964710/replacing-selected-text-in-the-textarea)

However, I can not assume that I am interacting with a normal `textarea`.

Possible nuances include:

- The text area being hidden inside an `Iframe`, which complicates the process of finding the element to interact with (`document.activeElement` may return the `Iframe`, rather than the element that actually contains the text).
- The `<textarea>` not being a `<textarea>`/`<input>` at all, but rather a [`contentEditable <div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable). The `.value` approach will not work in this case.

So I am searching for a flexible way to do this that can handle all edge cases elegantly.

---

### Some solutions I have tried:

- **option 1 :**
  I originally planned on storing the value in the system clipboard. Then, I could conceivably just use `document.execCommand('paste')` to modify the element. However, after trying it, this approach seems to have the same drawbacks as my initial approach. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130521/is-it-possible-to-fully-mimic-clipboard-functionality-using-the-chrome-extension)) 
   
   Additionally, this approach would delete whatever was in the clipboard before the operation. This is undesirable and any solution that utilizes this approach must provide a work around.
- **option 2 :** 
  Another option that I have considered is dispatching keyboard events for each character in the string. However, with this solution, you still run into the `Iframe` problem and it doesn't allow you do use special Unicode characters.  ┻━┻ ︵ヽ(`Д´)ﾉ︵ ┻━┻

Comment: I'll add a bounty to this quiestion (I personally find it interesting and non-obvious) as soon as I'm able (24h I guess)

Comment: By the way, an example to test those nuances would be YouTube comment entry box: it's a `<div>` inside an iframe.

Comment: How about inserting a string of unique characters via the keyboard dispatch events, and then doing `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(uniqueStr, injectStr)`. And in the case of an `input` you use `element.value`

Comment: i had a version of execCommand that i wrote for textareas, something like that might polyfill/facade your interaction enough to work

Comment: @dandavis you're leaving me hanging!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem consists of two subproblems:

1. Identify the target element of the contextmenu action.
2. Insert a custom text fragment at the caret (remove any selection if it is present).

### Subproblem 1: Identifying the target element

- If [crbug.com/39507](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39507) is resolved, then getting the element is easy. This feature request is almost 5 year old without any progress, so don't get your hopes high on this one.
  Alternative methods require you to break problem 1 in two more subproblems: Identifying the target frame, and then select the target DOM element.

There are several APIs that help with identifying the frame (use a combination of them, choose whichever combination fits best in your situation):

- The [`contextMenus.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) event provides the tab's ID (`tab.id`) as a property in an instance of [tabs.Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) and the frame's URL ([`frameUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#property-info-frameUrl)) in a separate object.
- The [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method can directly run a script in a frame.
  (currently only the top-level frame or all frames, targetting a specific frame is work in progress - [crbug.com/63979](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63979), planned for Chrome 42).
  Until targetting a specific frame is implemented, you could insert the content script in every frame and compare the URL with `frameUrl` (or use a combination of the next methods).
- Assuming that you have already inserted a content script with a [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) listener, use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) to send a message to a specific frame identified by `frameId` (since Chrome 41).
- Use the [`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#method-getAllFrames) method to get a list of all frames in a tab for a given `tabId`, then get the `frameId` of the target frame by filtering the list of frames by a known `frameUrl`.
- (in the future (Chrome 42?), `contextMenus.onClicked` will get the `frameId`).

Okay, assuming that you have the correct frame, you can simply use `document.activeElement` to get the target element, because input elements get focused upon click.

### Subproblem 2: Inserting a text fragment at the caret

If the target element is a `<textarea>` or `<input>`, then you can simply use

```js
// Assume: elem is an input or textarea element.
var YOURSTRING = 'whatever';
var start = elem.selectionStart;
var end = elem.selectionEnd;
elem.value = elem.value.slice(0, start) + YOURSTRING + elem.value.substr(end);
// Set cursor after selected text
elem.selectionStart = start + YOURSTRING.length;
elem.selectionEnd = elem.selectionStart;
```

Otherwise, you need to know whether there is a content editable element, and if so, remove any selection if existent, and finally put your desired text over there.

```js
var elem = document.activeElement;
if (elem && elem.isContentEditable) {
    // YOURSTRING as defined before
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(YOURSTRING);

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    // Remove previous selection, if any.
    sel.deleteFromDocument();
    // If there is no range in the selection, add a new one, with the
    // caret set to the end of the input element to avoid the next error:
    //"Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index."
    if (sel.rangeCount === 0) {
        sel.addRange(document.createRange());
        sel.getRangeAt(0).collapse(elem, 1);
    }
    // Insert new text
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(newNode);
    // Now, set the cursor to the end of your text node
    sel.collapse(newNode, 1);
}
```

Relevant documentation for the web platform APIs used in the last example:

- [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
- [`Selection.deleteFromDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.deleteFromDocument)
- [`Selection.collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.collapse)
- [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)
- [`Range.insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.insertNode)

Comment: Rob, thanks again for an absolutely stellar answer and great information on recent and future API features. I'll wait until OP can confirm this answer works for him before awarding the bounty - not that you really need it!

Comment: Supposing I have a frame ID, how do I get the document for that frame?

Comment: The following npm package is excellent for inserting text: https://github.com/grassator/insert-text-at-cursor