# Why can't I deliver this message to all of the frames running in a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

## Subject

I am creating a chrome extension that requires me to send a message from my event page to a **content script that is running on a specific frame**

The message passing operation is invoked when a context menu option is clicked. Said option is only available when the element in focus is categorized as `editable` by the [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) API. I need to send it to the innermost frame in which the element is contained. (so I can modify its contents by accessing the `document.activeElement` object)

As of Chrome 41, you are able to send a message to a specific frame by filling the value of the `frameID` parameter of the `options` argument to the [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) function.

However, Chrome 41 is currently in beta, so I obviously cant expect this feature to be compatible with my users' browsers.

So, I planned of sending a message to all of the frames in the tab (by registering listeners on a content script that had the [`all_frames`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) property set to true) . Once inside the content script  I could check to see if this was the right frame or not by comparing the value of `window.location.href` with the value I am expecting.

## Problem

It appears as If I had a misconception about the way that either event listeners or message passing works. The documentation makes it pretty clear that `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` is supposed to send a message to every frame in the tab, but it appears as if there can only be a single `chrome.runtime.onMessage()` event listener invoked per message, even if there are many listeners registered. Which one actually gets invoked appears to be somehow dictated by the initial loading of the page.

This can be demonstrated with a simplified version of my extension:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,

    "name":"Demo",
    "description":"This is a demonstration",
    "version":"1.0",

    "permissions":[
     "<all_urls>",
     "contextMenus"
     ],

    "background": {
       "page":"background.html",
       "persistent":false
    },

    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["content.js"],
        "all_frames":true
     }]
}
```

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE text/html>
<html>
 <head>
  <textarea id="temp"></textarea>
  <script src="event.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>                                                                                                                                                                   
</html>
```

event.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(requestHandler);  
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title":"Click Me!!",
    "contexts":["editable"],
    "id":"1"                                                                                                                                               
});

function requestHandler(info, tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"destination":info.frameUrl});

    //this should get sent to every frame in the tab
}
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleRequest);

alert("Hi, i'm: " + window.location.host);
function handleRequest(message)
{
    alert("You tried to send a message to: " + message.destination);
    alert("I am: " + window.location.href);
}
```

If you visit a page with many frames, like [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAivBjfVH0o&index=328&list=PLWtgg3L88Vrw2iUxU9fPPoMVkYTuMBzvG) you should notice the following behavior:

- You get many alerts upon the initial loading of the page, indicating that there are many frames being loaded (all with listeners)
- When you click the context menu option, only a single alert pops up, indicating that only a single frame received the message
- The frame that receives the message remains constant throughout multiple clicks of the context option, but is likely to change when you refresh the page. This indicates that the order in which the frames are initially loaded determines which frame is going to get your message.

---

So, how can I assure that the frame I am trying to talk with actually gets my message, without resorting to the `frameID` option that's only available in chrome 41?

At first I thought I could send a response back from the content script, indicating whether or not the message went to the right place. I could just keep doing this in a while loop in the event page until I got back a message telling me to stop, but like I said earlier, the message always seems to go to the same frame until the page is refreshed, so this approach does nothing for me.

## Additional Details

Something else I have noticed is that if there are two frames on a page with the same origin, like plus.google.com for example, both frames will respond to the message, if that is the frame set that the message happened to get delivered to. So, the recipient seems to be based on origin rather than by some unique frame ID.

Here is a link to a video I took of the phenomena I am speaking of:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVz8zBVqgIw&feature=youtu.be

Notice that I got alerts initially from: youtube.com, accounts.google.com, plus.google.com and client6.google.com, but only client6 got my message

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chromium 40.0.2214.91, even after fixing the syntax error in your code and adding `"permissions":["contextMenus"]` and `"all_frames":true`. Please try out your code before posting the question, to make sure that the code really represents your problem.

Comment: @RobW sorry, I fixed the errors, but What happens on your system? on mine, the behaviour is as I described. When the page is loading you should she alerts from: youtube.com, accounts.google.com, plus.google.com and probably some others aswell.  Then, when you click the option, you should notice that only one of the frames responds to the message.

Comment: Here, I see multiple alerts when I visit *youtube.com* and select a context menu option *in YouTube's search box*. Which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: @RobW Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)   Im going to to a screen cap and embed the video

Comment: @RobW check to make sure that the frames that load when you click the context message say "You tried to..." and "I am..." and aren't just frames that are loading late (say "Hi, i'm...")

Comment: I am getting 2 "I am" and 2 "You tried"s on YTs homepage, in a completely new Chrome profile with nothing else besides the extension in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70469/discussion-between-lukep-and-rob-w).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event listener calls `alert`. This method blocks the runtime until the dialog is closed. For some reason, this also prevents Chrome from correctly triggering the onMessage events in other frames (reported as [crbug.com/456482](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456482)).

A work-around is to use `console.log` for debugging instead of `alert`, or wrap the code within `setTimeout` to asynchronously process the `onMessage` event. E.g.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Message: ' + message);
    });
});
```