# Accessing document.activeElement.value from an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm still working on my first Chrome extension and I've hit a wall. I'm trying to insert some text into a text field using `document.activeElement.value`.

I can't get it to work at all. I've used tons of examples from a bunch of folks and haven't gotten it to work.

Here's my code in my `background.js` that the extension uses to create the context menu and insert the text. I'm assuming at this point something is wrong with my `onClickHandler` or click event but I'm at a loss.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "all";
  var title = "Test";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});
}); 

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

//The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler() {
    document.activeElement.value = 'some text';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you need some background.

First off, you're executing code in the background page; as such, `document` refers to the *background page itself*.

Take a moment to read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) (and maybe the rest of the page if you're starting out, it's very helpful).

If you read that, you should understand you need a content script. Once [injected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) in the active tab (and [the `"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) should be enough to do it from the click handler), you can access the proper `document`.

However, this task is more complex than you think. There was a recent discussion on the topic; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055887/is-there-a-flexible-way-to-modify-the-contents-of-an-editable-element) for details.