# How do I know which element was clicked in context menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

We develop extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. We want to add context menus to our extensions that will show when right clicking on any form element which is editable. I tried to add an editable context menu to Chrome:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Test editable menu item",
    "contexts": ["editable"],
    "onclick": function(info, tab) {
        console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
        console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
        console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
    }
});
```

But I need to know which element the user clicked on, and `info` and `tab` don't contain the element. How do I know which element the user clicked? I would like to have a jQuery object containing the element.

The `info` object contains the following attributes:

```
"editable": true
"menuItemId"
"pageUrl"
```

Comment: See "Subproblem 1" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28198957/938089

Answer (score 3):

One of the best workarounds I know of is to follow the advice given in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/th776vlEc2Y) to use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to inject a listener in the target page for the 'contextmenu' event.

Comment: That qualifies as a link-only answer. Please include relevant parts of the advice in here, your summary is too short.

Comment: Relevant snippet: "use document.addEventListener( "contextmenu", function... ) from a content script."

Comment: @AntonySargent there is no such `contextmenu` type for `addEventListener` what do you mean?

Comment: @S.W.G. - addEventListener is a function on the document object - it takes two arguments: 1: a string name of the event to listen for ('contextmenu' in this case), and 2: a function to be called when that named event fires, whose argument is an event object (in this case, a PointerEvent). You can experiment with this by opening the developer tools javascript console on a web page and running: `document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { console.dir(e); }); ` and then right click on some element in that page. The console will print a handle to a PointerEvent which you can examine.

Answer (score -2):

I know that is to late for you but I answer here for anyone else who's google it.

My solution was to create a mapping between created menu items and the business model (in this case a "data" array):

```
var itemsDic = {};
function onClickHandler(info) {
    alert(itemsDic[info.menuItemId]);
};

for(i in data) {
    var currentItem = chrome.contextMenus.create({
            parentId: item,
            title: data[i].ItemName,
            type: data[i].ItemType,
            contexts: ["editable"],
            onclick : onClickHandler
    });
    itemsDic[currentItem] = data[i];
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand the question. The question is not finding out which menu entry was clicked, but what was the HTML element the context menu was invoked on.