# How to copy/paste in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've just started learning to code last week so bear with me.  I want to make an extension that does the following.

1)When you right click on a textbox a custom context menu is opened

2)When the context menu item is clicked, the title of that context menu item will be pasted into the text box.

So far I have created all the context menus.  I just can't figure out how to copy/paste the title of the context menu item into the text box.  I've read about the documents.execcommand but I have no idea how to use it. Thanks.

```
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({

title:"hi",
onclick:copy,
contexts:["editable"]

});

chrome.contextMenus.create({

title:"bye",
onclick:copy,
contexts:["editable"]

});

function copy(info) {

};
```

Comment: Where is that code located?

Comment: The code is located in a JavaScript file background.js in the root folder of the extension.  It's the only code in the file.  I'm not sure if I answered your question.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055887/is-there-a-flexible-way-to-modify-the-contents-of-an-editable-element/28198957#28198957) can be of value. I'm not slapping a duplicate, but it's very relevant.

Comment: Doing a simple search on stackoverflow will get you lots of answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an api called [document.execCommand()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands) like what you mentioned. Its as simple as the code below:

```
var copyText = document.execCommand('copy');
```

Basically it will copy any text selection in the browser. Therefore it is not applicable with what you wanted to achieve.

Lastly, to change  the value of any element in a webpage, you must have enough knowledge about  [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Basically these are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM).