# How to replace input field selected text with Chrome extension context menu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a simple solution to change input field value with context menu trigger.

Let's say changing to `bar` will be enough, I'll try to add some processing later.

[This is how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGX2p.png)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "name": "test plugin",
  "version": "0.1"
}
```

background.js:

```
function getClickHandler() {
  //magic here
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "change to 'bar'",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["editable"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea would be

1. <del>Listen to `contextmenu` event in content scripts and record `e.target` (This is needed because we don't know the actual DOM node for chrome context menu api, see [Issue 39507](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39507))</del> We could directly use `document.activeElement`, since input elements get focused upon click
2. In background page, send a message to content scripts when `getClickHandler` is triggered
3. In content scripts, replace target.value with `"bar"`

Sample code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "name": "test plugin",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    replaceSelectedText(document.activeElement, request.text);
});

function replaceSelectedText(elem, text) {
    var start = elem.selectionStart;
    var end = elem.selectionEnd;
    elem.value = elem.value.slice(0, start) + text + elem.value.substr(end);
    elem.selectionStart = start + text.length;
    elem.selectionEnd = elem.selectionStart;
}
```

background.js

```
function getClickHandler(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: "bar"});
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "change to 'bar'",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["editable"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler
});
```

### Updated

As @Xan has mentioned in the comments, if you just want to update `<input>` field, then using `input.value = xxx` is ok; however if you would like to manipulate arbitrary editable element, see [Is there a flexible way to modify the contents of an editable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055887/is-there-a-flexible-way-to-modify-the-contents-of-an-editable-element) for more ideas.

Comment: Advanced reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055887/is-there-a-flexible-way-to-modify-the-contents-of-an-editable-element